# Using OpenCV in Java with JavaCV

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, opencv, javacv

I am getting desperate !! I am trying to use **OpenCV** in **Java**, via **JavaCV** (JNA to wrap OpenCV for java).

I am on **Mac Os X** 1.5.

I installed OpenCV, and I can compile and run the examples included. So that works.

Now I open **Eclipse**, and I create a new project, as described here :
http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

In that new project, only one small class with a call to a opencv function (I used the sample code) :

```
import static name.audet.samuel.javacv.jna.cxcore.*;
import static name.audet.samuel.javacv.jna.cv.*;
import static name.audet.samuel.javacv.jna.highgui.*;
import static name.audet.samuel.javacv.jna.cvaux.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IplImage image = cvLoadImage("test.png", 1);
        if (image == null) {
            System.err.println("Could not load image file.");
        } else {
            cvSmooth(image, image, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3, 0, 0, 0);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I have the following error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable
>   to load library 'cxcore':
>   dlopen(libcxcore.dylib, 9): image not
>   found

Please, I need help, I looked over google for hours, I don't know where to look for anymore.

Comment: @Matthieu: OSX users sometimes have a library compatibility issue between 32-bit or 64-bit VM. Can you try by the -d32 option as VM argument in starting Eclipse launch configuration

Comment: I added the code (this is the sample code from JavaCV). I tried the "-d32" argument, and I get the following error : "Cannot run Java in 32 bit mode. Continuing in 64 bit mode." Maybe it is that ?

Comment: @Matthieu: Could be. See http://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=12#c11. As your Eclipse is in 64 bit mode, you need to confirm you're using the 64-bit OpenCV version.

Comment: Yes but I explicitely compiled openCV in 32bits because my architecture is 32 bits (well I am fairly certain of that ! I have a macbook bought in 2009, the cheapest one). So I don't understand why Eclipse is in 64 bits ? Is there a way to know if my Mac is 32 ou 64 bits ?

Comment: @Matthieu: try http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/win/64bit.html

Comment: OMG my mac is 64 bits I had no idea !! Ok now I understand "a little" better. Thanks, I am going to re-compile OpenCV in 64 bits and try out. I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok that didn't work either (but at least I know I'm 64 bits), but I posted an issue on the JavaCV website and got this answer : "Ah, apparently they changed the names of the libraries on Mac OS X with the latest SVN version... " I'll try an older version of OpenCV and let you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out the SVN version was not compatible with JavaCV.

I downloaded the latest official version (2.1) and compiled it and installed it, and it works.

See http://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=19

Comment: for a simpler implementation also have a look here: http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/

Comment: Well well well it turns out that 2.1 release doesn't work (at least on my machine with OS X 10.5), but the SVN works in C++ programs. But the 2.1 is compatible with JavaCV, and not the SVN version. So for me now, OpenCV can work, but not JavaCV.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link these two libraries:

```
- javacpp.jar
- javacv.jar
```

In the JavaCV/lib-opencv/win_x86_64 you have to have files of your like:

```
 - msvcp100.dll
 - msvcr100.dll
 - opencv_core220.dll
 - opencv_calib3d220.dll
 - ...
```

These DLLs have to be compiled for your platform (win 32 / win 64 / Linux / etc.

You have to define path to your OpneCV DLL files:

```
-Djava.library.path=lib-opencv/win_x86_64/
- or the DLLs have to be somewhere in your system PATH of your operating system
```

Answer (score 0):

I had looked at this problem for a while, as the OP suggests all kinds of problems start crawling out of the woodwork. I went through a ton of StackOverflow posts to be able to come up with a relatively painless experience for setting up a OpenCV project in Java. I went through JavaCV and found that it did not meet my needs. I was however able to directly implement functionality referenced in OpenCV posts (C++ posts) but in the Java language when I used certain javacpp versions. I had a ton of compilation issues too since javacpp depends on compiled C++ libraries that must be native to the environment the user is in (something people that live in Java land love to not deal with). Anyway I was able to construct and environment with Maven. I use eclipse but this should work fine with other programming environments. I put up an example project to illustrate how to start build a bootstrap project and start working. 
The project compares 2 images, given their URLs. It's a equality test, wither the images are identical or not. Hopefully this can help folks setup and get working in this environment and avoid the tons and tons of pitfalls that I encountered when trying to work with OpenCV in Java (I was in the exact same place as OP mentally at that time :) ).

The example:  https://github.com/darkhipo/ImgzCmp